# How can i retrieve column value in db table, without repeatedly retrieving the same value multiple times

Tags: mysql

I'm using mysql. I have a table, eg: `tbl_person` with columns `id, name, place`.
Now I would like to retrieve all places starting with A. So my query is:

```
select place from tbl_person where place like 'A%';
```

The issue here is, if there are multiple records in the table with place='America', the retrieved list will have value 'America` multiple times. But I need to have same place name to occur once the retrieved list. How can it be achieved??

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT PLACE FROM TBL_PERSON WHERE PLACE LIKE 'A%' GROUP BY PLACE
```

would work

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DISTINCT` construct:

```
select distinct place from tbl_person where place like 'A%';
```

Answer (score 0):

select distinct(place) from tbl_person where name like 'A%';

You use distinct keyword to remove the duplicate values.

Answer (score 0):

Select DISTINCT place from tbl_person where place like "A%";